# Mongodb ParseError with certain parameter

Tags: mongodb

My code is as follows:

```
var collection = db.collection(merged_client_collection);
    collection.findOne({_id: datetime.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:00:00")}, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, doc);
        } else {
            callback(err, doc);
        }
    });
```

And it turns out with an error: "Error: parseError occurred"
No idea what is wrong. It happens with some date time, but others is fine.

Help.

Comment: On the mongodb server side, there is an error: "SocketException handling request, closing client connection: 9001 socket exception [2] server"

Comment: Where are you getting `datetime` from?

Comment: @chridam, like 'new Date(req.params.datetime)', and I will provide parameter '2016-02-23 11:00:00'

Comment: "It happens with some date time, but others is fine." - do you know what is exact date, which causes the error?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve exactly? Are you looking to filter documents based on a particluar date/time on the `_id`?

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin Some cases will cause the error, and yesterday there are two times, but today most of the date time failed.

Comment: @chridam I wanna fetch data and display it. That is all.